# setting custom density for an emulator

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator

I have been trying to make emulator with 200 dpi, that is between mdpi and hpdi.

here is what i have tried so far

[image]

and in manifest declaring

`android:anyDensity="true"`

but this doesnt creates an emulator of 200dpi infact it the emulator created by this is of 240dpi. 
that is the emulator can only be of 120 or 160 or 240 dpi.
any value in between this rounded off to upper band that is 80 --> 120; 200 --> 240 and so on.

I want to test my application for Tablet which has 170dpi, and in no way I am able to create an emulator with such configuration.

As of now I am unable to get proper result for this issue and 2-3 questions having same issue but no satisfying answers or comment.

Supposing that emulator with densities other than 120, 160, 240, or 320 dpi cant be made.
So is it possible to create a configuration in eclipse's graphical layout with 170 dpi or 200dpi so that I can make an alternative resources for that device.
[image]

other than providing High, ,medium, low or xHigh value, is there a way to provide custom value.

looking forward for your help

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @will brown : Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch your emulator before run the application using the AVD manager.
This way you can set to "scale display to real size, and then, get the DPI you need

Comment: I had been launching emulator the way you suggested, but it doesn't make any difference. Because "scale display to real size" is used to emulate the diagonal screen size of the device wrt your monitor's dpi.